# Error when following along TensorFlow for R tutorial

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio

I'm following along a tutorial in RStudio at this link [text](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/keras/regression.html) which takes us through building a simple deep neural network for building a regression model using the Auto dataset. I'm working with TensorFlow and Keras 2.10 installed into a conda environment and accessed via R package "reticulate".

I could follow along correctly until the following two statements:

```
normalizer <- layer_normalization(axis = -1L)
```

I corrected this error by using the following statement after researching the web:

```
normalizer = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=-1)
```

(will not work with "<-")

Next statement is also giving me an error:

```
normalizer %>% adapt(as.matrix(train_features))
```

```
    File "<string>", line 1  
    normalizer %>% adapt(as.matrix(train_features))  
                ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It identifies the "%>%" pipe symbol in R as invalid syntax. I'm lost for how to resolve the error. Any help will be helpful

Expected (half-expected) that the command will work and instead got an error